# How to make svg sprite a regular picture?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have such a picture for the background. It should be made normal and put in background

```html
<svg class="iphone-background__img" viewBox="0 0 991 828" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_f_479_2171)">
    <path d="M726.689 447.055C636.6 301.175 399.748 283.135 292.584 292.35C204.911 229.864 267.12 198.986 369.452 84.6792C471.785 -29.6278 716.462 36.8959 857.979 37.8365C999.495 38.777 1120.33 339.695 1101.17 471.585C1082.02 603.476 839.301 629.405 726.689 447.055Z" fill="#FA00FF" fill-opacity="0.2" />
  </g>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_f_479_2171" x="0.806396" y="-232.258" width="1352.37" height="1059.42" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="125" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_479_2171" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: By 'normal' you mean PNG?

Comment: You can use this [URL-encoder for SVG](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Comment: @Azu yes PNG....

Comment: There are many SVG to PNG convertors online.

Comment: You don't need to convert the image to PNG to use it as a background image. Browsers will display an SVG file as a background image.

Comment: This might help you: https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/how-to-add-svgs-with-css-background-image/